# Orange - rewriting data by making new rows based on column values

Tags: python, orange

I am trying to process covid-19 cases data

(the source, for interest: https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/blob/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv)

The data forms a matrix, listing dates in columns and countries in rows. A simplified view:

```
country 1/20/20 1/21/20 1/22/20 ... etc. ...
China   100     120     144     ... etc. ...
US      0       0       1       ... etc. ...
...
etc.
...
```

I am trying to turn the date columns and the figures into two new features, say "date" and "confirmed", for as in:

```
country date     confirmed
China   1/20/20  100
China   1/21/20  120
China   1/22/20  144
US      1/20/20  0
US      1/21/20  0
US      1/22/20  1
...  etc.  ...
```

I am interested in any solution that embeds in Orange, though - of course - we can prepare the data before importing it!

Comment: See [`pandas.wide_to_long()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html). You might make it work in Orange's Python Script Widget.

Comment: Having developed the script, I found this process isn't a very good idea, because the long denormalised result isn't easily filtered this way. If you consider doing this, orange might be the worng tool for your data, or you might be looking at your data with a bias (denormalising, for me) that doesn't help with Orange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to do it in a script or with canvas? With (pure) canvas, I guess you can't. You can of course always use a Python script widget and do it there.

In a script (standalone or within canvas) you should treat `Orange.data.Table` as immutable, although this is not enforced by Orange itself. A few versions back the obsolete methods that could change the number of rows were removed. You can still change the data in-place, but I wouldn't recommend it.

You will have to create a new table that will have the appropriate size from the start. I guess the simplest way to do it would be to collect all the data you need in a Python list (of lists) and then pass it to `Table.from_list`.

Disclosure: I'm one of Orange developers and I'm in the middle of writing a blog post using exactly this data. It's going to be a series and we would also show some scripts like this in a week or two.

Comment: "with Canvas I guess you can't" - I'd got that far (though I didn't want to discount some hidden tool. The question generalises to any matrix). I started to look at the script widget and found how wonderfully documented it is :) I'm afraid I haven't got the PhD yet.

Comment: Re: disclosure, I teach computing, and I started some work explaining things that can be done with this data using observable and in video. Do reuse any part (https://observablehq.com/@boisvert/covid-19) I'm also interested in supporting any effort communicating work on this.

Answer (score 0):

Janez's answer gave exactly the information I needed, thank you.

Here I post the code for the python script in Orange, to give a complete solution for the problem.

```
from Orange.data import Domain, TimeVariable, ContinuousVariable, StringVariable, Table

# toISODate: parse the date string and returns it in ISO format
def toISODate(s):
    bits = s.split('/')
    year = '20'+bits[2];
    day = bits[1]
    day = day if len(day)==2 else '0'+day
    month = bits[0]
    month = month if len(month)==2 else '0'+month
    return year+'-'+month+'-'+day

# Prepare output domain
tmVar = TimeVariable.make("Date");

out_domain = Domain([ContinuousVariable.make("Lat"),
                     ContinuousVariable.make("Long"),
                     tmVar,
                     ContinuousVariable.make("Count")],
                    [],
                    [StringVariable.make("Country"),
                     StringVariable.make("Region")]
                   )

# Prepare output source - list of lists
out_source = []

in_domain = in_data.domain # not really needed
in_width = len(in_domain) # oops - thank you @community for the reminder

# outer loop through original data rows
for in_row in in_data:
   lat, long = in_row[0], in_row[1] # grab latitute, longitude
   country, region = in_row.metas[1], in_row.metas[0]
   # inner loop through dates in each row
   for j in range(2,in_width):
      date = tmVar.parse(toISODate(in_domain[j].name)) # find date (in clolumn names), parse to UNIX
      # make new row: lat, long, date, number of cases, country, region
      out_row = [lat, long, date, in_row[j], country, region]
      out_source.append(out_row)
   # end
# end in_row

# Make data from the list
out_data = Table.from_list(out_domain,out_source)
```

Ideally, the code should be written to deal generally with any matrix (turning column x, row y, value into the tall table with three colums x, y, value ; then dealing with supplementary colums). My Python isn't up to it (yet).

additionally, one can replace the 'in_width' value in the inner loop by 'in_data.domain.attributes'. doing so will ensure the loop will cover the ever increasing nb of columns (one new every day)

Comment: oops - thank you "community" - in_width needs to be set correctly or replaced...

Comment: The code now in use in this tutorial: https://youtu.be/6hMGWoSc_vU ; thank you @JanezD